# This TableRow layout or its TableLayout parent is possibly useless

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a warning in an xml file: This `TableRow` layout or its `TableLayout` parent is possibly useless.

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
      ...       
</TableRow>
```

I put the attribute `android:id` in there, but the warning didn't disappear.

Any ideas as to what may be causing the warning?

Comment: can you show your code ......this is not enough code to identify..put code before that TabRow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
tools:ignore="UselessParent"
```

to your table row to avoid warning or in the tag where you get the warning.

Comment: this will ignore the warning only ..but what will be better remove code or use this ..

Comment: If you need the parent tag in your layout than just remove warning, and if you dont want parent tag thar replace it by direct child tag.

Comment: ya this thing will be better to replace parent...using instead of tools:ignore

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not the best solution, it is *terrible* practice to ignore warnings.  Unless the warning comes from a bug in the compiler or linter itself, eliminating the warning is almost always a better option than ignoring it.

In this case, as the responses to the accepted answer indicate, all you have to do is remove the `TableLayout` parent of `TableRow`.  The warning is most likely there because you have a table with only one row, so the `TableLayout` is unnecessary.

E.g. Change this:

```
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
        ...
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

To this:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...
</TableRow>
```

Comment: While I understand the dangers of ignoring warnings, I have had this particular message and have ignored it because in that particular case it made sense to me to do so.  I was creating a table with a single row in XML, then adding rows programmatically, and therefore I needed the TableLayout as well as the single TableRow.  I could have added the first row programmatically during onCreate, but logically it made much more sense to me to put it in the XML and tolerate the warning.

Comment: @Matthew that makes perfect sense, you make a good point.  In that case, you're not really ignoring the warning because you know the `TableLayout` is going to be filled with children, so it's not useless. Thus, the warning serves the purpose of bringing a possible issue to your attention, and you've established with certainty that it's not an issue because you programatically address it, so it makes sense to quiet the warning.